# how to insert multiple data with same foreign key

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

How to insert multiple data into mssql without using loop?
i'm developing a clinic management system, while doctor may give few medicines to patient,therefore i hope inside my database,the data will look like

```
|-----------------------------------|
|   RecordID  |  ItemID   |   Amount|
|-----------------------------------|
|      1      |     1     |    10   |
|      1      |     2     |    100  |
--------------------------------------
```

and now what i get is...

```
|-----------------------------------|
|   RecordID  |  ItemID   |   Amount|
|-----------------------------------|
|      1      |     1     |    10   |
|      2      |     2     |    100  |
--------------------------------------
```

because i'm using store procedure and needed loop to store all "ItemID" into sql.

```
+------------+     +-----------------+     
| record      |     | record_items    |     
+------------+     +-----------------+    
|RecordID(PK)|  >  | RecordID (FK)   |  
|PatientID   |     | ItemID          |     
|Precription |     | Amount          |
|VisitDate   |     +-----------------+
+------------+
```

this is my 2 tables, i hope when storing data ,the recordID will not increase based on how many ItemID inserted.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPatientRecord]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @PatientID INT,
    @Prescription VARCHAR(50),
    @VisitDate DATETIME,
    @ItemID INT,
    @Amount INT

AS

SET NOCOUNT On

    DECLARE @RecordID INT


        INSERT INTO record VALUES(@PatientID,@Prescription,@VisitDate)
        SET @RecordID=Scope_Identity()

    INSERT INTO record_item VALUES(@RecordID,@ItemID,@Amount)


RETURN
```

this is my stored procedure

Comment: Post your code for Store Procedure

Comment: I'm hoping this is homework. Your questions sound basic for someone apparently developing a life critical system. Have you considered integrating a third party electronic prescribing system or perhaps purchasing an entire a clinic management system rather than trying to build one yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will potentially have multiple `record_items` for each `record`, you need to have two stored procedures: one to write `record` (once) and one to write each of the `record_items` associated with the record.

In order to make this work correctly, after writing `record` you will need to retrieve the `recordid` so that it can be passed to the stored procedure for `record_items`.

Here is a rough outline for the stored procedures; the rest of the work I'll leave up to you.

One note: the RecordId is returned to the caller since it is an output parameter. This means that you will need to execute this procedure using a command (which you should be doing anyway) and will need to retrieve that value of this parameter after the stored procedure has been executed.

Here is the `record` sp:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPatientRecord]
    @RecordId      INT OUTPUT ,
    @PatientID    INT,
    @Prescription VARCHAR(50),
    @VisitDate    DATETIME
AS

    INSERT INTO record VALUES(@PatientID,@Prescription,@VisitDate)
    SET @RecordID=Scope_Identity()
```

and here is the `record_items` sp:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPatientRecordItem]
    @RecordID     INT,
    @ItemID INT,
    @Amount INT

AS
    INSERT INTO record_item VALUES(@RecordID,@ItemID,@Amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT INTO SELECT` to insert all at once. Check [this](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html) for more info.

---

Regarding your problem, possibly you are inserting the same value in `RecordID` and `ItemID`. Only with some code we can tell you more.